# Add django template tags to templates with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, django-templates

I've got a django management command which is modifying templates & I'd like to include a django `{% if` template tag to conditionally include a block so that if `message_url` is not defined, exclude the following content;

```
<tr>
    <td>
        If you cannot view this message, please go to the
        <a href="{{ message_url }}">
            Members Hub
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The `<a>` tag is passed to a function to be modified so this seemed like the perfect place to include the condition string because the parent(s) are available & the template tag could be added in the `<tr>` or `<td>`;

```
def replace_tag(template, string, template_origin, template_type):
    """
    :param template: HTML content
    :type: str or unicode
    :param string: new string for HTML link
    :type: str or unicode
    :param template_origin:
    :type: str or unicode
    :param template_type: MessageType.key of template
    :type: str or unicode
    :return: modified HTML content
    :rtype: unicode
    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup(template)
    link = find_link(soup, template_type)
    if link is not None:
        link.string.replace_with(string)

        row = link.parent.parent
        if '{% if message_url %}' not in row.contents:
            row.contents.insert(0, NavigableString('{% if message_url %}'))
        if '{% endif %}' not in row.contents:
            row.contents.append(NavigableString('{% endif %}'))
        # '{% if message_url %}' + row + '{% endif %}'
```

At first I just added my tags as plain strings to the content and they were added to the `Tag` contents, but don't appear to end up as part of the template.

So I modified it to add the strings as `NavigableString` objects, but that then results in `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute '_is_xml'`

Comment: For what it's worth, modifying templates on the fly like this seems terribly dangerous to me. Can't you achieve the same thing just with conditional logic in the template itself?

Comment: So if I cannot see the message, I should go to the Members Hub. How do I tell that, when I don't see the message?

Comment: @solarissmoke Agreed, but due to regulatory changes we're having to update emails that we've sent out. So these email templates are stored in the database, not on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after digging around some more I've found [`insert_before`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after), [`insert_after`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) and [`new_string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) to achieve what I wanted;

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(template)
link = find_link(soup, template_type)
if link is not None:
    link.string.replace_with(string)
    row = link.parent.parent
    if '{% if message_url %}' not in row.contents:
        row.insert_before(
            soup.new_string('{% if message_url %}')
        )
        row.insert_after(soup.new_string('{% endif %}'))
```